# Access $(this) element inside .load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove `loader icon` from images after they have been loaded. In order to do that, I need to access `$(this)` but I cannot access the image element and remove `js-image-loading` class.

variable `html` contains dynamic `HTML` contents fetched via ajax.

```
    $(html).find('img').load(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("js-image-loading"); //ok image is done loading, remove icon
    });
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: what error you see? I can  see you've not quoted to 'html'

Comment: no errors, `js-image-loading` class won't remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to quote to the html selector `$(html)` should be `$('html')` but I suggest you to use `*`:

```
$('*').find('img').load(function() {
   $(this).removeClass("js-image-loading");
});
```

Or, simply `$('img').load()`

Comment: As I commented on one of the other answers here, this is what the **"...a simple typographical error"** off-topic close reason is for. Questions where typos are the cause of the problem should be commented on and voted to close, not answered.

Comment: Also: "html" could've just as well been an actual jquery collection of the DOM, saved earlier in the code, not a wrong selector. So downvoting the other valid answers is just wrong.

Comment: why `*` ..? wouldn't it collect all the elements and search them one by one, rather than a single search starting from the root..? I believe it will cause many unnecessary searches..

Comment: @JamesDonnelly this is why I proposed this [feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273266/2333214)....

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("html").find('img').load(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("js-image-loading"); //ok image is done loading, remove icon
});
```

OR

```
$('img').load(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("js-image-loading"); //ok image is done loading, remove icon
});
```

NOTE: html is string not object

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bhewxedr/3/)**